# Vender 0ption autoWrap is not working Geo Server 2.10.1

Tags: geoserver, xml

I have added a vender option of code for autoWrap to my xml and it does not seem to be working.  I have used multiple different pixel lengths to see if I could see the update but I have not been able to see any change as a yet.  In my reading, I came across a statement that autoWraping needs to be [enabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1eKfR.png).  as I went further down the rabbit hole I could not find any documentation on that.  listed below is the screenshot of the polygon I am watching to see if the .xml changes take as well as a snippet of the code I am editing.

[image: Screen Shot]

```
         <sld:Rule>
        <ogc:Filter>
          <ogc:PropertyIsLike wildCard="*" singleChar="#" escapeChar="!">
            <ogc:PropertyName>building</ogc:PropertyName>
            <ogc:Literal>*</ogc:Literal>
          </ogc:PropertyIsLike>
        </ogc:Filter>
        <sld:MinScaleDenominator>0</sld:MinScaleDenominator>
        <sld:MaxScaleDenominator>3600</sld:MaxScaleDenominator>
        <sld:Name>Yes</sld:Name>
        <sld:Title>Building</sld:Title>
        <sld:PolygonSymbolizer>
          <sld:Fill>
            <sld:CssParameter name="fill">#d4d6e4</sld:CssParameter>
          </sld:Fill>
          <sld:Stroke>
            <sld:CssParameter name="stroke">#d4d6e4</sld:CssParameter>
            <sld:CssParameter name="stroke-width">0.5</sld:CssParameter>
            <sld:CssParameter name="stroke-linejoin">round</sld:CssParameter>
          </sld:Stroke>
        </sld:PolygonSymbolizer>
        <sld:TextSymbolizer>
          <sld:Label>
            <ogc:PropertyName>name</ogc:PropertyName>
          </sld:Label>
          <sld:Font>
            <sld:CssParameter name="font-size">12</sld:CssParameter>
            <sld:CssParameter name="font-family">Nimbus Sans L Regular Condensed</sld:CssParameter>
          </sld:Font>
          <sld:LabelPlacement>
            <sld:LinePlacement>
              <sld:PerpendicularOffset>0</sld:PerpendicularOffset>
            </sld:LinePlacement>
          </sld:LabelPlacement>
          <sld:Fill>
            <sld:CssParameter name="fill">#749dae</sld:CssParameter>
          </sld:Fill>
          <sld:VenderOption name="autoWrap">20</sld:VendorOption>
          <sld:VendorOption name="maxDisplacement">50</sld:VendorOption>
          <sld:VendorOption name="labelAllGroup">TRUE</sld:VendorOption>
          <sld:VendorOption name="removeOverlaps">TRUE</sld:VendorOption>
          <sld:VendorOption name="followLine">TRUE</sld:VendorOption>
          <sld:VendorOption name="group">TRUE</sld:VendorOption>
          <sld:Halo>
            <sld:Radius>
              <ogc:Literal>0.26</ogc:Literal>
            </sld:Radius>
            <sld:Fill>
              <sld:CssParameter name="fill">#bce6f4</sld:CssParameter>
            </sld:Fill>
          </sld:Halo>
        </sld:TextSymbolizer>
      </sld:Rule>
```

Answer (score 2):

I moved it down in the list and now it works.  very odd

```
   </sld:Fill>
          <sld:VendorOption name="maxDisplacement">50</sld:VendorOption>
          <sld:VendorOption name="labelAllGroup">TRUE</sld:VendorOption>
          <sld:VendorOption name="removeOverlaps">TRUE</sld:VendorOption>
          <sld:VendorOption name="followLine">TRUE</sld:VendorOption>
          <sld:VendorOption name="autoWrap">40</sld:VendorOption>
          <sld:VendorOption name="group">TRUE</sld:VendorOption>
          <sld:Halo>
            <sld:Radius>
              <ogc:Literal>0.26</ogc:Literal>
            </sld:Radius>
            <sld:Fill>
              <sld:CssParameter name="fill">#bce6f4</sld:CssParameter>
            </sld:Fill>
```

Comment: seems odd, if you can reproduce it on 2.14.x or 2.15.x please raise a bug